# instancemethod object has no attribute '___getitem__'

Tags: python, pyfits

I am on PyCharm (community edition 4.0.2) retrieving data from a .fits file.
z = data.field [SDSS_Z] results in 
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '**getitem**'.
On other Field of the same .fits file I have no problems

```
import pyfits
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np
plt.close('all')
hdu = pyfits.open('cat.v9.group_v22.fits')

print hdu[1].columns

data = hdu[1].data

u = data.field('U')
r = data.field('R')
k = data.field('LOG_MSTELLAR_KS')
morph = data["GZ1_MORPHOLOGY"]              
lum = data["L_O3"]                          
z = data.field ["SDSS_Z"]
```

Comment: As Arnaud P noted you just have a syntax error in the last line.  Note you can also just do `data['SDSS_Z']` which is equivalent to `data.field('SDSS_Z')`.  I see that in your code you are using both conventions.  Best to to just stick with one, but for stylistic purity and to prevent confusion like this in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the lines you say work ('U', 'R', etc..), it seems you simply went astray with the syntax on the last one. Just keep to what you've been doing:

`z = data.field("SDSS_Z")`

And it should roll fine.